# Core data, iCloud, and Cloudkit

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I am in the planning stage of a new project that will require to use Core Data.  It has these requirements:  1.  Be able to access same data across multiple devices.   2.  Be able to access same data in offline or online  3.  Guarantee data will not be lost.

Couple years ago, I embarked on similar project.  But I had to abandon these features.

Does Core Data with iCloud syncing work well enough for current iOS 7 and 8 to warrant another attempt?

If not, I am thinking about using CloudKit and local Core Data storage.  But then I will have to write extra code to update both.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use [Ensembles](http://ensembles.io).

Comment: I would use `CoreData with iCloud syncing`. It seems to work now and there are lots of WWDC videos on `CoreData`. Plus the `CoreData` debugging in iOS 8 is much improved and you can use `developer.icloud.com` to see what's being written to the CoreData store. `CloudKit` has no offline storage so you will need to use CoreData and then sync between CoreData and CloudKit - could be tricky. As always, the issue with accessing data from multiple devices simultaneously is conflict resolution and no technology will provide that for you out-of-the-box (except last write wins, of course)

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao It's a CloudKit library with support for local caching (not Core Data, but files using NSCoding)

Comment: This one has support for CoreData. Check out. CKSIncrementalStore https://github.com/CloudKitSpace/CKSIncrementalStore